# Continuar cuando hay excepcion de login en Instaloader python

Tags: python, txt, instagram

estoy usando el módulo de Instaloader para descargar perfiles de manera rápida, cuando un perfil es privado el programa tira un error y no sigue con la lista, lo que qiero conseguir es que cuando una cuenta requiera login, la omita y continue.

```py
import instaloader  

time = int(input("Enter the number of random users that you want to download: ")) download.

def main():
    def gather(name): 
        instaloader.Instaloader().download_profile(name,profile_pic_only=False) 
    for i in range(1, time): 
        try: 
            with open('followers.txt', 'r') as f: 
                for line in f: 
                    gather(line.strip()) 

        except: 
            continue;
```

Lista de usuarios:

```
Usuario1
Usuario2(Requiere Login)
Usuario3
```

Comment: Usa un [bloque try-except](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: @DanteS. y en el except que debería poner?

Comment: El tipo de error que recibes. Puedes obtenerlo del modulo que usas.

Comment: @DanteS. eso lo entiendo pero me refiero a que debe hacer al detectar ese error (instaloader.exceptions.LoginRequierdException)

Comment: Puedes simplemente usar la palabra pass, que significa "no hagas nada" y entonces el bucle continuará tranquilamente. También puedes usar "continue" como hace el compañero Roberto en su respuesta, continue significa, volvé al principio del bucle sin ejecutar lo que viene despues.

Comment: Te sirvió mi comentario???

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que se rompa el ciclo, podrías utilizar algo parecido a esto

```
try:
    main(line.strip())
except:
    continue;
```

con esto lograras que cuando haya un error, continué con el ciclo en proceso en la posición que se encuentra

Comment: En lo posible, hay que evitar el uso del except que captura cualquier error, ya que si ocurre un error no relacionado, será mucho más dificil de detectar.

Comment: @DanteS. Hola, un gusto saludarte dante, claro totalmente de acuerdo con tu comentario, mas sin en cambio, se podría agregar una excepción espera en la parte del except para llevar un control adecuado

Comment: Hola, un gusto también?

Comment: Buenas, me sigue ocurriendo lo mismo, simplemente no continua, deja de funcionar al encontrar una cuenta que requiere login. @RobertoEspiritu

Comment: No debería de suceder eso @vat, el except sin especificar el error captura todos los errores. Un código dentro de un Try **no puede mostrar un error en pantalla**

Comment: @DanteS. Ahora no me da ningun error pero en vez de continuar descargando los demas perfiles se queda estancado en ese y el programa se cierra, cambiando el orden, las cuentas publicas se ejecutan en cadena pero cuando llega una que requiere login el programa se cierra.

Comment: De casualidad pusiste tooodo el bucle for dentro del try-except?

Comment: @DanteS.dentro del bucle for esta el try y except

Comment: Quizá se genera un error cada vez que intentas logearte cuando la primera vez falla. Hacé que el except sea así: `except BaseException as err: print(err)` y dime que imprime. Y mejor sigamos en los comentarios de la pregunta, por que la persona que hizo la respuesta debe estar odiando las notificaciones.